# I am getting CORS error when calling grail api from angular front end

Tags: api, grails, cors

I am having a grails api which is hosted in azure. Below is the configuration of application in application.yml

```
grails:
  cors:
  enabled: true
  allowedHeader: ["Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With"]
  allowedMethods: [GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS]
  maxAge: 3600
  allowedOrigins: "*"
```

When running locally it is working just fine but when i deploy it to azure and call any api ,it gives me CORS error.

Any help/suggestion is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

I think you add the config in the wrong format. You can try this:

```
grails:
  cors:
    enabled: true
```